# 3d Camera in OpenGL and SFML

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, camera

I am trying to make my scene in OpenGL move, but I am having trouble. I have looked up several tutorials and know the mathematical concepts behind OpenGL matrixes. I am just having trouble with this. All I need is like 1 example. If I could see an example of how the "camera" moves in one direction when a key is held down, I can modify the code for my own purposes.

Comment: How are you setting up your view matrix right now?

Comment: I am using   `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  glLoadIdentity();  gluPerspective(90.f, 8.f/6.f, 1.f, 100.f);`  and `glPushMatrix(); glTranslate(); glPopMatrix();`

Comment: When I google "how to move a camera in OpenGL", the first result is http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm - have you read that page, and still don't get it?

Comment: "*I can modify the code for my own purposes.*" While simultaneously having no idea how it works. You need to understand how things work, not just copy, paste, and modify some example code.

Answer (score 3):

Well, OpenGL does not really have a "camera". What it has is a transformation pipeline (either fixed function, or programmable). Also OpenGL does not maintain a "scene" but just draws points, lines and triangles to a framebuffer, one at a time.

Once you've wrapped your mind around the fact, that you're essentially not a very different thing like using any other drawing API (`goTo(x,y); lineTo(x,y);` or similar) a lot of things in OpenGL make a lot more sense.

So a "camera" in OpenGL is merely a viewing transformation applied at some point in the vertex transformation pipeline. Usually as the last transformation in the modelview matrix – model transformation followed by view transformation, hence model-view.

There are many ways to specify the view transformation, and a typical helper function often used for this is `gluLookAt`. Since transformations are applied in the opposite order they're multiplied onto a matrix (if OpenGL's glMultMatrix or one of the built in matrix manipulation functions is used, at least) the viewing transformation comes first, when defining the modelview matrix. So in your drawing function the code usually looks like

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadMatrix(view.transformation) # same as glLoadIdentity(); glMultMatrix(view.transformation)

foreach(object o in objects):
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glPushMatrix()
    glMultMatrix(o.transformation)

    o.draw()

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glPopMatrix()
```

Did you notice how I always make sure I'm in the right matrix mode before each matrix manipulation? That's because object::draw may switch to another matrix mode (like say GL_TEXTURE), and switching matrix modes has only neglectible cost, so you should always do it, before a sequence of matrix manipulations.

As a further hint: You should always place your code for setting viewport and the projection matrix at the beginning of the drawing code. *Do not* place it in a window's resize event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gluLookAt` to "move" your camera.

```
gluLookAt(eyex,eyey,eyez, centerx,centery,centerz, upx,upy,upz);
```

They first 3 coordinates are the coordinates of your virtual eye. The next 3 are the coordinates where your eye "looks" at. The last 3 is a vector pointing towards the up direction of your scene (think of it as rotating your eye).

For example,

```
gluLookAt(1,1,1, 0,0,0, 0,1,0);
```

This makes your eye at (1,1,1) and you're looking at the origin. The direction of the up vector is the positive y-axis.

If you want to move the camera, you could call `gluLookAt` with updated parameters each time a key is pressed from your keypress callback function.